# type deduction failed for std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I am writing a customized `deque` with limited size. According to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back), there are two overload functions for `push_back`, one is for lvalue, the other one is for rvalue. So I use `std::forward` in my customization of `push_back` method. But there are compilation errors saying

`error: no matching function for call to ‘forward(A&)' this->push_back(std::forward(e));`

`/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:76:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr _Tp&& std::forward(typename std::remove_reference<_From>::type&)
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept`

`/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:76:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
custom_dequue.cpp:14:43: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Tp’
             this->push_back(std::forward(e));`

```
class A{
public:
    int m = 9;
};

template<typename T>
class sharpdeque: public std::deque<T>
{
public:
    static const std::size_t limit = 20;
    void push(T&& e){
        if(this->size() >= limit){
            this->pop_front(); 
            this->push_back(std::forward(e));
            LOG(warning)<<"deque limit is reached";
        }

    }
};
```

with later call

```
sharpdeque<A> q;
q.push(A());
```

can somebody explain which part I did wrong? and possibly also the reason why it is wrong.

Comment: That isn't how `std::forward` should be used. That function has no type deduction. That is a plain-old rvalue reference parameter. You already declared what `T` is when you instanced your `q` object.

Comment: You probably meant `this->push_back(std::move(e));`

Comment: Read the linked duplicate for an explanation of why you need to specify the template argument for `std::forward`. In your case you should be using `this->push_back(std::move(e));`

Comment: Got it now, it should be  `push_back(std::forward<T>(e));`, this one works fine.

Comment: @Allanqunzi Yes, it works, but `forward` is the wrong tool to use in that case. Your `push` function only accepts rvalues, so the right thing to do would be to `push_back(std::move(e));`, this is what `forward` achieves too, but `forward`'s typical use case is when you have a forwarding reference parameter that can bind to both lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: @Praetorian, no, I don't agree. 'push(T&& e)' here is [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), `forward` is suitable here, i.e., it will forward to either `void push_back( const T& value )` or `void push_back( T&& value )` depending on if rvalue or lvalue is passed to `e`.

Comment: @Allanqunzi No, it's not a universal reference (which is now officially known as a forwarding reference). Try passing an lvalue to `push` ... `A a; q.push(a);`

Comment: @Praetorian, you are right. On the `g++`(4.9.2), it doesn't compile when passed to a lvalue. But what should I do if I want to achieve the `forward`ing effect, to make my `push` function accept lvalue and rvalue both, and call `std::deque::push_back` accordingly?

Comment: @Allanqunzi You need `template<typename U> void push(U&& e) { ... }`. Or add an overload that deals with lvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it now.